# should i have to give them money back when they owe me vacation pay?

Tags: vacation

I was recently let go on a job and was expecting a check for two day. when I checked my account I was paid for the whole week. I did have vacation time that I didn't use, but the employers office guy called and said that he messed up and that he will get with me Monday to get the money back I was only owed 40% of what was deposited. note I never received a pink slip or a check for my vacation or anything. should I have to pay them back?

Comment: I would suggest that the official papers get in before giving the money back. But I know that where I live, if the employer pays you too much, you have to give the money back. At least that's what I was told.

Comment: What country/state?

Answer (score 2):

If they can prove that they overpaid you based on their existing policies, you have to pay them back.

You need to look over the handbook and see how your vacation was accrued and how much you used.  Check your pay stubs as well. They should show you how many hours of personal or vacation time you were owed.  Most companies have you accrue personal time on a per hour worked basis.

Comment: In many places companies are not required to pay out for unused vacation time. The company policy should be in their manual. He may not be owed anything for vacation time.

Comment: I agree. I specifically said " based on their existing policies"  :)

Comment: The OP stopped being bound by company policy the moment they left the job. Only the contract applies, and only to the extent that it is legal.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask for an explanation on paper what money they should have paid you.

Do the calculation yourself in the meantime. Post that to them.

I am a little supposed that a company is unable to sort out pay.cannot imagine what their invoice department is like